# Dynamic String input in C

Tags: c, string, dynamic, input

I'm doing a program for my Computing I class in which I must take words input from the screen (standard input) and convert the words to Pig Latin.

I can convert a single word to Pig Latin easily enough; my issue is with the input. The user will enter any number of words on any number of lines, then enter five periods (".....") on a new line when the input is complete. The example given by the professor is:

the quick brown fox 
jumped over the lazy dog 
because it would not move 
.....

How could I separate each line of input into individual words without knowing how many words (or lines) that the user will enter?

Comment: the function you are looking for have the word "scan" or "get" in them

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc,char** argv) {
  char input[64];
  char* token = 0;

  // get a line from input
  while(fgets(input, 64, stdin)) {
     // check for terminating characters
     if(strncmp(input, ".....", 5) == 0) break;
     // tokenize the input
     token = strtok(input, " ");
     while(token) {
       // token contains each word
       token = strtok(NULL, " ");
     }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't use `gets()`. It is so vile and evil it has officially been deprecated from the language and will not be part of the next standard release. use `fgets()` instead, which offers self-guided protection from buffer overflows.